# Image loses it's original result when passing it to another activity

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap, android-camera-intent

I am working on a camera feature in my application. I am capturing an image and passing it to another activity. The problem that I'm facing is when I display the image in another activity it loses its original result (gets pixilated) for some reason. This is how I'm doing it:

```
private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(EnterDataView.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }else {
            String[] permissionRequest = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            requestPermissions(permissionRequest, 8675309);
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK || resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                Intent passPhoto = new Intent(this, Photo.class);
                passPhoto.putExtra("byteArray",mphoto);

                passPhoto.putExtra("Caller", getIntent().getComponent().getClassName());
                startActivity(passPhoto);
            }
        }
    }
```

Getting the image in other activity like this:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
            //ImageView _imv= new ImageView(this);
            /*Bitmap _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);*/
            Intent intent_camera = getIntent();
            Bitmap camera_img_bitmap = (Bitmap) intent_camera
                    .getParcelableExtra("byteArray");
            //_imv.setImageBitmap(_bitmap);

            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, mGallery, false);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.id_index_gallery_item_image);
            //String uri = getPhotos.getString(getPhotos.getColumnIndex(("uri")));
            //Uri mUri = Uri.parse(uri);
            //img.setImageURI(mUri);
            //byte[] blob = getPhotos.getBlob(getPhotos.getColumnIndex("image"));
            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
            //bmpImage.add(bmp);
            img.setImageBitmap(camera_img_bitmap);
            mGallery.addView(view);

        }
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id_index_gallery_item_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_300sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks okay at a glance, could you provide the layout file which you are using to display it? Could it be that the image is being distorted or stretched by the size or scale of the ImageView it is being loaded into?

Comment: @Harry Might be...I've uploaded the xml too please have a look

Comment: @3iL try removing `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: @Navneetヅ, I did but it didn't work

Comment: @3iL to pin this issue to this, you could try to remove the `layout_marginTop`, `layout_marginLeft` attributes, and change the values of both `layout_height` and `layout_width` from `@dimen/_300sdp` to `wrap_content`. Doing this should display the image in its raw form without any size or scale changes. If it's still distorted after this, it could be a different issue entirely!

Comment: You are getting thumbnail only from `data.getExtras().get("data");`. To get full size image, you have to do additional work. Go through this doucmentation for detail information https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html. What @hasan_shaikh has done gets the job done , but s/he has not posted full code like method `createImageFile`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method which you have used will not work on all the devices above marshmallow.
Follow this,

add this in your manifest.xml

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="yourpackagename.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
    </provider>
```

create provider_path in xml folder of your resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
</paths>
```

then add this in your activity,
declare a global variable

```
private Uri mUri;
private static final String CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER = "com.yourpackagename.fileprovider";
 private void takePicture() {
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = createImageFile();
        mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER, file);

        Log.d("uri", mUri.toString());
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA_STORAGE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_STORAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (mUri != null) {
                String profileImageFilepath = mUri.getPath().replace("//", "/");
                sendImage(profileImageFilepath);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Picture wasn't taken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

this is createImageFile()

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "APPNAME-" + timeStamp + ".png";
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "FOLDERNAME");
    File storageDir = new File(mediaStorageDir + "/Images");
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
    return image;
}
```

and finally, pass profileImageFilepath to our next activity to display

Comment: This will work but I would have expect little more details and If you are trying to provide full code, you are missing `createImageFile()`  implemenation.

Comment: What is createImageFile()?

Comment: go through this https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html , it has implemenation for that method as well.

Comment: @Jimmy  I have added createImageFile method in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

In this line I get error:

```
private static final String CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER =      
  "com.yourpackagename.fileprovider";
```

This line is correct:

```
private static final String CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER = 
  "com.yourpackagename.provider";
```

instead fileprovider write provider or use this

```
mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```

My problem is solved. Thank you very much.
Very good work.