# Crash when try to open camera android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I need to open camera and take picture and display in imageview.

But problem is I am getting crash as below. I cleaned the build and ran. But still this problem occurs.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.trial.learn/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180515_104113_6007506636120272936.jpg
                                                                     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
                                                                     at com.trial.learn.MainActivity.openCamera(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                     at com.trial.learn.MainActivity.checkCameraPermission(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                     at com.trial.learn.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6998)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Here is code. I am clueless what mistake I am doing. Kindly correct me.

I even added permissions in manifest file too.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath,mCurrentPhotoPathResize;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        checkCameraPermission();
    }
    private void checkCameraPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            if (!checkPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, 123))
                checkPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, 123);
            else openCamera();
        else openCamera();
    }
    private void openCamera() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            File photoFile2 = null;
            try {
                photoFile = ImageResizeUtility.createImageFile(this);
                photoFile2 = ImageResizeUtility.createImageFile2(this);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            mCurrentPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            mCurrentPhotoPathResize = photoFile2.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.e("url",mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Log.e("urls",mCurrentPhotoPathResize);

            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.trial.learn.authority", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 111);
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkPermission(Activity context, String permission, int requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                    new String[]{permission},
                    requestCode);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ImageResizeUtility.compressImage(this, mCurrentPhotoPath, mCurrentPhotoPathResize, imageView);
            String _imagePath = mCurrentPhotoPathResize;
            Log.e("urlOnActivity",_imagePath);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 123:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    openCamera();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

xml/file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.trial.learn/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

**android manifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.trial.learn.authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and `createImageFile` functions , maybe both,  so that we can see how you setup a path.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859506/image-loses-its-original-result-when-passing-it-to-another-activity/49859730#49859730

Comment: @hasan_shaikh thanks. Camera is opening but x ( close is working and displaying as picture not taken) but tick button in camera is not working. When clicked, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int CAMERA_REQUEST = 2000;
```

Open Camera on button click..

```
 public void openImageChooser() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

And in onActivityResult fetch the bitmap and set it in ImageView

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {

   if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frontimg)).setImageBitmap(photo);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Camera with CameraIntent:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 200);
```

Get Captured Image in onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case 200:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                if (data != null) {

                    Bitmap cameraImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


                    imageView.setImageBitmap(cameraImage);

             }
            }
         }
```