# Camera taking picture rotated

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);

        cameraButton = findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

For some reason the code above rotates the picture after it is taken. I tried uploading a picture below to show what I mean. Not sure if StackOverflow added it

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859506/image-loses-its-original-result-when-passing-it-to-another-activity/49859730#49859730

Answer (score 2):

Yes for that you have to manage it with the help of EXIFINTERFACE

Write below code into your onActivityResult() method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format( new Date( ));
output_file_name = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + timeStamp + ".jpeg";

File pictureFile = new File(output_file_name);
if (pictureFile.exists()) {
    pictureFile.delete();
}

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

    Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface(pictureFile.toString());

    Log.d("EXIF value", exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
    if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
        realImage= rotate(realImage, 90);
    } else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("8")){
        realImage= rotate(realImage, 270);
    } else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
        realImage= rotate(realImage, 180);
    } else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
        realImage= rotate(realImage, 90);
    }

    realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

    fos.close();

    imageView.setImageBitmap(realImage);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d("Info", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: This will help to solve your problem. If you are satisfied with my answer please accept the answer. To accept my answer click on the arrow given to the left of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't know how to resolve 'data.length' and all the rotate functions called with realImage and degree in the parameters