# Intent to bitmap creates a tiny image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, camera

I followed [this guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/camera-application-create/) to take over the camera for an app I am developing

The problem is however when converting the image to a bitmap like the guide does, the size of the image becomes tiny, now usually I am able to take good pictures with the camera on the device with good resolution, so I doubt that is the problem, The bitmap size becomes 153 - 204.

Anyone got a clue what I am doing wrong or why it turns out tiny and/or how I can prevent this. (Resizing the bitmap is not an option because or the graphics becoming messy)

Code to convert (just like the guide):

```
private void CameraButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
  StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
  FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.wmImageView1).SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859506/image-loses-its-original-result-when-passing-it-to-another-activity/49859730#49859730 check sendImage(uri)

Comment: Only the thumbnail is returned, you need to retrieve the full size image: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics