# Problems with saving photo from Camera for Oreo

Tags: android

For Oreo 26 only i am getting this issue

from onActivityResult 
mImageCaptureUri.getPath() returns null

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859506/image-loses-its-original-result-when-passing-it-to-another-activity/49859730#49859730

Comment: Can you post your code for camera intent?

Comment: @hasan_shaikh I changed <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/> to <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/> Its working thanks..,

Comment: Upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the provider_path xml

```
<external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
```

It wil work