# how to get base64string from camera and file to post it to server?

Tags: java, android, base64, android-camera, android-bitmap

i'm trying to convert image bitmap to base64string to post it to server but it won't works. it just load so long and then failed.

this is my code onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requenstCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requenstCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requenstCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            selectedImageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap);
        } else if (requenstCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                selectedImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap);
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        selectedImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

please help how to make it works

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859506/image-loses-its-original-result-when-passing-it-to-another-activity/49859730#49859730 once u get the image uri convert it to base64

Comment: why do you want to convert it to base64? it will only increase your data size to 133% of original size - just upload it as it is - no base64 needed at all

Comment: how do i upload it as it is? @pskink

Comment: using okhttp / retrofit / any other similar library

Answer (score 0):

Don't use base64 string for uploading image. Compress your image and upload your image on server

Here is a simple php script

```
  <?php

$target_dir = "img/";
$target_dir = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$response = array();

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) 
{


     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) 
     {
          $success = true;
          $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
     }
     else 
     {
         $success = false;
         $message = "Error while uploading ". $target_dir;
     }
}
else 
{
     $success = false;
     $message = "Required Field Missing";
}

$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Create an interface for FileUpload

```
public interface FileUploadService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("upload.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );

    @GET("images/{imageName}")
    Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> getImage(@Path("imageName") String imageName);
}
```

On Android Side Use Retrofit to upload compressed image to server

```
file = new File(imagePath);


    FileUploadService service =
            getRetrofit().create(FileUploadService.class);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(imageUri)),
                    file
            );

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(body);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
            String resource = BASE_URL + "images/" + file.getName();
            sendMessage(resource, recieverBareid);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("Upload", "failed");
        }
    });
```