# Capture image with camera using FileProvider, how to store uri

Tags: android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I have followed tutorials such as [this](http://www.zoftino.com/android-capture-image-from-camera-and-save), [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954) or [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media) about how to use FileProvider to take a picture with the camera and store it on a temp file for later upload.

They all generate a file, get the uri using file provider, and then call the CAmera intent with this uri:

```
 val intent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (uri != null) {
            try {
                if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, resultCode)
                }
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                Timber.e(t, t.message)
            }
        }
```

Then on `onActivityResult` they get the image using:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                              Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
           //don't compare the data to null, it will always come as  null because we are providing a file URI, so load with the imageFilePath we obtained before opening the cameraIntent
        Glide.with(this).load(imageFilePath).into(mImageView);   
        // If you are using Glide.
    }
}
```

So to quote this tutorial "load with the imageFilePaht we obtained before opening the cameraIntent".

For the most part it works, but when I try with the emulator for some reason my activity is destroyed when the camera app is launched (probably low memory) and my reference of the Uri is null when I come back from the camera.

Can I retrieve this Uri from the result of the activity? Or do I really have to store it in sharedpreferences or similar?

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859506/image-loses-its-original-result-when-passing-it-to-another-activity/49859730#49859730

Comment: Did you provide permissions & uses feature? https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: Please read my question, @hasan_shaikh yours is the same solution I have, I am just missing the mUri now cause the activity was recreated.

Comment: @pskink and Phillipp those are not my problem

Comment: Please check my answer, you will get the uri path as well

Comment: @hasan_shaikh that is not my problem, in your answer you store the uri in a field of the class, my class is wiped when the camera gets opened, so next time that field is null!

Comment: data is empty on activity result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and my reference of the Uri is null when I come back from the camera

Save that `Uri` in your saved instance state `Bundle` of whatever activity or fragment is calling `startActivity()` to start the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` app. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.12/Camera/FileProvider) for a complete implementation of an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request that does this.